# How to fix npm errors without writing sudo in macOS?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, node-modules, sudo

I have to write sudo before running any npm command in my VS code terminal in MacBook Air (OS: macOS Sonoma 14.4).
Example: sudo npm install
sudo npc create-react-app my app
If I didn't "sudo" the command will not execute, while others users are doing without writing sudo.

FYI: I have node.js v20.10.0 and npm version 10.2.4 installed globally in my system.

Comment: It sounds like node is installed in a place that root owns. I would recommend installing a version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) then everything will live in your home directory. As an aside `create-react-app` is no longer maintained and is not recommended for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your PATH. First evaluate the node path:

```
sudo which node
```

In `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`, add the line with the evaluated `node_path`:

```
export PATH="node_path:$PATH"
```

In the end, you need to restart a shell or source the file.